# Implement an unique key constraint in ADF BC

Tags: oracle-adf

I have a table for the users to add records. In my requirement, for one of the column, I should not allow the user to enter duplicate value.

This is not primary key field. How to validate the column for duplicate on click of save button and it should show an error message.

Example
If i have a countries table shown to the user to add countries and it consists of columns

- country id (not primary key)
- country name

I want the country id to be unique. When the user enters a duplicate value it should display an error message on click of save button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an [Alternate Key Constraint on the EO](https://blogs.oracle.com/imc/entry/adf_and_alternate_unique_keys) and then use the [UniqueKey Validation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/b31974/bcvalidation.htm) to validate the key value at commit time.

Comment: Thanks, based on your suggestion found a blog for its detailed implementation [Defining Unique Key Constraints for Non-Primary Key Attributes in ADF-BC](http://www.baigzeeshan.com/2012/03/defining-unique-key-constraints-for-non.html0)

Comment: The link in the above comment is broken, see: http://www.baigzeeshan.com/2012/03/defining-unique-key-constraints-for-non.html